# La forma más eficiente de generar un csv en java 1.4 y enviar por response

Tags: java, csv

Mantengo un proyecto antediluviano basado en java 1.4.2 y struts. De momento he podido resolver y desarrollar casi cualquier cosa, pero se me ha presentado una situación donde me han surgido dudas. En este caso he de generar, partiendo de un `resultset` un csv al vuelo que el usuario descarga después de realizar la petición.

Funcionar funciona, pero dado que no he podido utilizar ninguna librería de generación de csv por la antigüedad del entorno, me preguntaba si lo que estoy haciendo es eficiente. Actualmente generar un csv de +120000 filas cuesta unos 6 minutos en entorno de desarrollo (se reduciría a la mitad aproximadamente en producción).

He aquí partes del código:

```java
response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                               "attachment; filename=\"exportacio_selectiva.csv\"");
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/comma-separated-values; charset=UTF-8");            
            ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

            //"interceptamos" clause de DBEntityList.
            //contiene los campos from y where de los filtros utilizados en la lista
            String clause = cloneOptimizedList.getClause();
            String[] clauseList = clause.split("FROM");
            String whereClause = clauseList[1];
            //hacemos la llamada a bbdd con nuestra query
            List dataToExport = getExportList(whereClause,exportId,tableName);
            //convertimos el resultado en campos csv separados por ;
            StringBuffer csvContent = getStringForCsv(dataToExport,exportId);

            byte[] content = csvContent.toString().getBytes();
            response.setContentLength(content.length);
            outputStream.write(content,0,content.length);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

private StringBuffer getStringForCsv(List data, String columns)
    {
        //eliminamos la , final         
        columns = columns.substring(0, columns.length() - 1);               
        columns = columns.replaceAll(",", ";");
        StringBuffer csvContent = new StringBuffer();
        csvContent.append(columns+System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        for ( int i=0 ; i<data.size() ; i++ )
        {
            //no podemos usar StringUtils de Apache por obsoleto
            //asi que hay que recorrer la lista de listas creando el string con separador ;
            ArrayList temp = (ArrayList) data.get(i);
            for ( int j = 0 ; j < temp.size() ; j++ )
            {
                if (temp.get(j)==null)
                {
                    csvContent.append("''");
                }
                else{
                    csvContent.append(temp.get(j).toString());
                }

                if (j != temp.size()-1)
                {
                    csvContent.append(";");
                }
                else
                {
                    csvContent.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }
            }       

        }

        return csvContent;
    }
```

¿Alguna sugerencia?

**EDIT**: Agrego el código del método `getExportList`

```java
private List getExportList(String filters, String columns, String tableName)
    {

        EntityManager em = new EntityManager();
        Connection conn = em.getConnection();
        //columns = columns.substring(0, columns.length() - 1);
        HashMap map = new HashMap();
        if (tableName.equalsIgnoreCase("TSC_ATM"))
        {
            TableMapCard tm = TableMapCard.getInstance();
            map = (HashMap) tm.getMap();
        }
        else
        {
            TableMap tm = TableMap.getInstance();
            map = (HashMap) tm.getMap();
        }       

        columns = columns.substring(0, columns.length() - 1);
        String[] columnsList = columns.split(",");
        String translatedColumns = "";
        for (int j=0; j<columnsList.length; j++)
        {
            translatedColumns += map.get(columnsList[j])+",";
        }
        translatedColumns = translatedColumns.substring(0,translatedColumns.length()-1);        



        log.error(COGALogger.SERVER_ERROR, "EXPORT COLUMNS: "+translatedColumns);
        String query = "SELECT "+ translatedColumns.toUpperCase() +                         
                " FROM " +filters.toUpperCase();                
        log.error(COGALogger.SERVER_ERROR, "QUERY EXPORT VALIDATIONS: "+query);
        try {           

            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);          
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
            String[] columnList = columns.split(",");
            List result= new ArrayList();
            while (rset.next())
            {
                List row= new ArrayList();
                for (int i=1 ; i<columnList.length+1 ; i++)
                {
                    row.add(rset.getObject(i));
                }               
                result.add(row);
            }
            stmt.close();           

            return result;

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: ¿No puedes migrar a un Java más moderno? En Java 5 se añadió la clase StringBuilder, que es equivalente a StringBuffer pero sin métodos sincronizados, lo que la hace mucho más rápida. El código de tu aplicación debería seguir funcionando sin problema

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que lo hagas "en streaming", es decir, en lugar de leer todo y pasarlo a un `List` y luego procesar todo en un String y luego escribirlo en el output, yo iríra escribiendo mientras leo de la BBDD, eso hace el proceso mucho más eficiente desde el punto de vista de la memoria, la gestión del GC en Java 1.4 es muy ineficiente, comparada con los JDK actuales. Si añades el método `getExportList()` te podría hacer una propuesta con código.

Comment: @PabloLozano no, no puedo migrarlo. El proyecto es muy grande, de hecho consta de unos 10 proyectos de eclipse interrelacionados entre sí. Mi primer intento fue con StringBuilder pero vi que solo estaba disponible desde 1.5

Comment: @Roberto suena bastante interesante lo que propones. Edito el mensaje original y agrego el código.

Comment: ¿Cuanto te tarda la consulta SQL si no generas el CSV? Me extraña que te tarde 6 minutos por ineficiencia en la generación de strings. ¿Podrías descartar que fuese un problema de rendimiento en el acceso a la base de datos?

Comment: @ordago ejecutándola en el entorno de sqldeveloper es prácticamente inmediata

Comment: @RafaJ perdona que insista porque me sigue pareciendo raro, ¿has probado cuanto te tarda ejecutando la consulta desde Java, no desde el sqldeveloper? ¿Estás escribiendo trazas? Especialmente si están en algún bucle que se ejecute muchas veces

Comment: @ordago perdona, te he contestado algo que no habías preguntado. Efectivamente he mirado desde java. Por los controles que he ido estableciendo (sencillas salidas por log con su timestamp) el problema es la generación del contenido del csv. Aún así voy a repetir pruebas por si se me ha escapado algo.

Comment: @ordago he realizado otras pruebas y parece que, en efecto, algo hay de tapón en la parte de la consulta. Concretamente, y dado que he comprobado que no hay problemas de acceso a la bbdd, parece que es cosa del paso de los datos a las estructuras de lista. Quizá algo como lo propuesto por Roberto pudiera solucionarlo, aunque la verdad de momento no sé como implementarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente he podido resolver el problema por dos frentes. En primer lugar he vuelto a la idea de la concatenación de campos propuesta por @darrey que me facilita bastante las cosas para el siguiente paso. En segundo lugar, como propuso @Roberto ahora el fichero se descarga en streaming. He modificado el método `GetExportList` para que reciba como parámetro el `ServletOutputStream` y el bucle ha quedado así:

```java
String row = "";

while (rset.next())
{
    row = rset.getObject(1).toString()+System.getProperty("line.separator");
    out.write(row.getBytes(),0,row.getBytes().length);              

}
stmt.close();                       
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Ahora el tiempo total depende de la velocidad de descarga desde el servidor al cliente, que es bastante más rápida incluso en entorno de desarrollo. Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Has valorado el que desde la consulta devuelvas el String para el CSV?
Podrías componerlo concatenando los valores separados por las comas e incluir el ; final.
De este modo, la consulta te devolvería los strings listos para el CVS

Comment: Lo pensé al implementarlo al principio pero se descartó por que el código genera la consulta de manera agnóstica a las tablas. Los campos no siempre son los mismos, además, porque es una exportación selectiva de campos que se eligen desde la interfaz web.

Comment: Puedes hacerlo adaptando el translatedColumns a concat de los campos. No debería afectarte que sean más o menos campos, ni el número de tablas que cruces. Y en caso de nulos, puedes usar NVL

Comment: La verdad es que cuesta poco rehacer el código para probarlo. Gracias por la sugerencia. Voy a ello.

Comment: Probado y, por desgracia, descartado. He hecho las pruebas un par de veces con 61000+ registros y ha tardado lo mismo que antes de modificar el código, quizá unos segundos menos, pero apenas. Gracias de todas maneras, valía la pena probar.

Comment: Respecto a la mejora que has hecho, ¿Porque no incluyes el separador de linea en la consulta? Tal como lo tienes ahora, haces una carga de la property, cuando si lo metes en la consulta no deberías hacerlo.